# MicroROS build_agent.sh fails

Tags: c++, c, linux, docker, cmake

I'm following the tutorial for microROS for teensy found here

https://micro.ros.org/docs/tutorials/core/teensy_with_arduino/

Everything up to the build step works ok, but build fails, error output below, but before we get to that, I wanted to provide some more context:

Building this inside a docker container on Nvidia Jetson Nano 4GB (B01)

```
/etc/nv_tegra_release
L4T BSP Version:  L4T R32.7.1
```

I tried it with several container images found here:

https://github.com/dusty-nv/jetson-containers

ROS2Foxy:

```
dustynv/ros:foxy-ros-base-l4t-r32.7.1
dustynv/ros:foxy-pytorch-l4t-r32.7.1
```

When I launched the docker container in both tests I used either:

```
./scripts/docker_run.sh -c dustynv/ros:foxy-ros-base-l4t-r32.7.1
./scripts/docker_run.sh -c dustynv/ros:foxy-pytorch-l4t-r32.7.1
```

once inside the docker container This is the bit where it all goes south:

## Build step

```
ros2 run micro_ros_setup build_agent.sh
```

Below the parts of the output trace that are relevant:

```
[Processing: micro_ros_agent]                                       
[Processing: micro_ros_agent]                                       
[Processing: micro_ros_agent]                                       
[Processing: micro_ros_agent]                                        
[Processing: micro_ros_agent]                                         
--- stderr: micro_ros_agent                                           
Cloning into 'xrceagent'...
Switched to a new branch 'ros2'
HEAD is now at 3eb56b5 Release v2.3.0
Cloning into 'spdlog'...
HEAD is now at eb322062 Bump version to 1.9.2
CMake Warning (dev) at /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:438 (message):
The package name passed to `find_package_handle_standard_args` (tinyxml2)
does not match the name of the calling package (TinyXML2).  This can lead
to problems in calling code that expects `find_package` result variables
(e.g., `_FOUND`) to follow a certain pattern.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
cmake/modules/FindTinyXML2.cmake:40 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
/opt/ros/foxy/install/share/fastrtps/cmake/fastrtps-config.cmake:51 (find_package)
CMakeLists.txt:153 (find_package)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

/microros_ws/install/micro_ros_agent/lib/libmicroxrcedds_agent.so.2.3.0: undefined reference to `fmt::v6::internal::basic_data<void>::signs'
/microros_ws/install/micro_ros_agent/lib/libmicroxrcedds_agent.so.2.3.0: undefined reference to `vtable for fmt::v6::format_error'
/microros_ws/install/micro_ros_agent/lib/libmicroxrcedds_agent.so.2.3.0: undefined reference to `int fmt::v6::internal::snprintf_float<double>(double, int, fmt::v6::internal::float_specs, fmt::v6::internal::buffer<char>&)'
/microros_ws/install/micro_ros_agent/lib/libmicroxrcedds_agent.so.2.3.0: undefined reference to `fmt::v6::internal::error_handler::on_error(char const*)'
/microros_ws/install/micro_ros_agent/lib/libmicroxrcedds_agent.so.2.3.0: undefined reference to `char fmt::v6::internal::decimal_point_impl<char>(fmt::v6::internal::locale_ref)'
/microros_ws/install/micro_ros_agent/lib/libmicroxrcedds_agent.so.2.3.0: undefined reference to `fmt::v6::internal::basic_data<void>::zero_or_powers_of_10_32'
/microros_ws/install/micro_ros_agent/lib/libmicroxrcedds_agent.so.2.3.0: undefined reference to `char fmt::v6::internal::thousands_sep_impl<char>(fmt::v6::internal::locale_ref)'
/microros_ws/install/micro_ros_agent/lib/libmicroxrcedds_agent.so.2.3.0: undefined reference to `std::locale fmt::v6::internal::locale_ref::get<std::locale>() const'
/microros_ws/install/micro_ros_agent/lib/libmicroxrcedds_agent.so.2.3.0: undefined reference to `typeinfo for fmt::v6::format_error'
/microros_ws/install/micro_ros_agent/lib/libmicroxrcedds_agent.so.2.3.0: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > fmt::v6::internal::grouping_impl<char>(fmt::v6::internal::locale_ref)'
/microros_ws/install/micro_ros_agent/lib/libmicroxrcedds_agent.so.2.3.0: undefined reference to `int fmt::v6::internal::format_float<long double>(long double, int, fmt::v6::internal::float_specs, fmt::v6::internal::buffer<char>&)'
/microros_ws/install/micro_ros_agent/lib/libmicroxrcedds_agent.so.2.3.0: undefined reference to `spdlog::details::log_msg::log_msg(spdlog::source_loc, fmt::v6::basic_string_view<char>, spdlog::level::level_enum, fmt::v6::basic_string_view<char>)'
/microros_ws/install/micro_ros_agent/lib/libmicroxrcedds_agent.so.2.3.0: undefined reference to `int fmt::v6::internal::snprintf_float<long double>(long double, int, fmt::v6::internal::float_specs, fmt::v6::internal::buffer<char>&)'
/microros_ws/install/micro_ros_agent/lib/libmicroxrcedds_agent.so.2.3.0: undefined reference to `fmt::v6::format_error::~format_error()'
/microros_ws/install/micro_ros_agent/lib/libmicroxrcedds_agent.so.2.3.0: undefined reference to `fmt::v6::internal::basic_data<void>::hex_digits'
/microros_ws/install/micro_ros_agent/lib/libmicroxrcedds_agent.so.2.3.0: undefined reference to `fmt::v6::internal::basic_data<void>::digits'
/microros_ws/install/micro_ros_agent/lib/libmicroxrcedds_agent.so.2.3.0: undefined reference to `int fmt::v6::internal::format_float<double>(double, int, fmt::v6::internal::float_specs, fmt::v6::internal::buffer<char>&)'
/microros_ws/install/micro_ros_agent/lib/libmicroxrcedds_agent.so.2.3.0: undefined reference to `fmt::v6::internal::basic_data<void>::zero_or_powers_of_10_64'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[5]: *** [micro_ros_agent] Error 1
make[4]: *** [CMakeFiles/micro_ros_agent.dir/all] Error 2
make[3]: *** [all] Error 2
make[2]: *** [micro_ros_agent-prefix/src/micro_ros_agent-stamp/micro_ros_agent-build] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/micro_ros_agent.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
---
Failed   <<< micro_ros_agent [10min 2s, exited with code 2]

Summary: 1 package finished [10min 48s]
1 package failed: micro_ros_agent
1 package had stderr output: micro_ros_agent
```

I have also tried to completely reformat the SD card for the Jetson and start fresh. Same problem. So far I have spent 2 fulls days trying to overcome this problem. I think it is time to throw up my arms and ask for some kind soul out there to provide some insight!

Comment: This seems to be a bug in the resources (tutorial or sourcecode) that you were using, I would say. Is there something like a bugtracker for those to see if others found this as well and perhaps developed workarounds or fixes?

Comment: I did have it working at some point a few weeks back, But nothing on my end has changed. So far I have re-flashed the SD card 8 times. Sometimes I tried to use JetPack 4.6.3 and also 4.6.1. Also tried different docker container and even building the container images. Nothing but problems.